# Выскакивает ошибка "Invalid floating point operation"

Tags: delphi

Код на Delphi. После запуска ввожу в поле значение для H (с запятой, т.к вещественное число), запускаю сию процедуру. Выскакивает ошибка "Invalid floating point operation". Помогите найти, пожалуйста.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  Xmin = -3.0;
  Xmax = 3.0;
var
  W, y, H, x: real;
  i: integer;
begin
  i := 1;
  x := Xmin;
  Series1.Clear;
  H := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  StringGrid1.Cells[0, 0] := 'x';
  StringGrid1.Cells[1, 0] := 'W';
  StringGrid1.Cells[2, 0] := 'y';
  repeat
    if ((x > 0.1) and (x < 2.0)) then
      W := ln(x) + Exp((1 / 3) * ln(x))
    else if (x <= 0.1) then
      W := 4 * x + Exp(2 * ln(Sin(x)))
    else
      W := 2.6 * Exp(2 * ln(x) - 3.7);
    y := (ln(Exp(2*ln(W)) + W + 1) * cos(4 * x)) / (Exp(-2) + 2);
    Series1.AddXY(x, y);
    StringGrid1.Cells[0, i] := FloatToStr(y);
    StringGrid1.Cells[1, i] := FloatToStr(W);
    StringGrid1.Cells[2, i] := FloatToStr(x);
    x := x + H;
    i := i + 1;
  until x >= Xmax;
end;
```

Comment: Делайте Debug сборку. Запускайте в отладчике. Идите по шагам и проверяйте на какой строке будет вылет и какие там значения переменных.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в этой строке:

```
W := 4 * x + Exp(2 * ln(Sin(x)))
```

Потому что не бывает логарифмов отрицательных чисел. После того как вы поправите логику для этой строки, аналогичное произойдёт ещё далее:

```
y := (ln(Exp(2*ln(W)) + W + 1) * cos(4 * x)) / (Exp(-2) + 2);
```